# Matrix Multiplication Algorithm Breaks

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to implement simple matrix multiplication with 3 loops , o(n^3) , I saw this algorithm many times but it doesn't seem to work with , the program breaks right after the first iteration of the second loop , as for my code , it prints until "second loop" one time and the it breaks , here's my code

```
vector<vector<int>> getMultiplication(vector<vector<int>> a , vector<vector<int>> b , int r1 , int c1 , int r2 , int c2){
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    cout << r1  << "\n" << c1 << "\n" << r2 << "\n" << c2 << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        cout << "first loop" << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++){
            cout << "second loop" << "\n";
            ans[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < r2; k++) {
                cout << "third loop" << "\n";
                ans[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: You have not set `ans` size

Comment: @MBo isn't the vector type dynamically allocated?

Comment: No. How can it know that it should contain N rows and M columns?

Comment: @MBo thx mate that was indeed the issue

Comment: @hosnyhany You can get away with omitting the size if you populate a std::vector with `.push_back`; but when you are trying to access `ans[i]`, vector `ans` must already contain at least `i+1` elements.